# How to insert one js array object, into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

```
 let opts = {
   'environment': [{
     'name': 'file',
   }]
 }


 let containerName = {
   'containerOverrides': [{
     'name': 'ecsTask'
   }]
 };

 let overrides = ???

 console.log(overrides)
```

Where the console log produces:

```
{
   'containerOverrides': [{
     'name': 'ecsTask'
     'environment': [{
       'name': 'file',
     }]
   }]
}
```

This will match object specifications for runTask in aws ECS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#runTask-property

I'm not sure what belongs after let overrides =

I have tried, assign(), map(), append(), calling to the array with [0], push(), no success.

For example:

let overrides = Object.assign(containerName.containerOverrides[0], opts)

returns:

```
{
  environment: [{
  name: "file"
}],
  name: "ecsTask"
}
```

and

let overrides = Object.assign(containerName, opts)

returns:

```
{
  containerOverrides: [{
  name: "ecsTask"
}],
  environment: [{
  name: "file"
}]
}
```

let overrides = containerName.containerOverrides.map( d => ({...d, ...opts}) )

returns:

```
[{
  environment: [{
  name: "POSTMAN_COLLECTION_URL"
}],
  name: "ecsTask"
}]
```

Comment: Could you share an example of what you've tried? I would have thought a simple (though it does mutate containerName) way of doing it would be `Object.assign(containerName.containerOverrides[0], opts);` is that one of the things you've tried?

Comment: I thought it would too, but it doesn't give me containerOverrides in that case. Added snippet to question. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Object.assign mutates the first argument, so in this case `containerName.containerOverrides[0]` gets the opts and containerName would have the data you want for overrides.

Comment: Thanks again added an example of let overrides = Object.assign(containerName, opts), however that does not insert the environment into the array. It adds them side by side like above example I added.

Comment: I think some thing like this could do the trick `containerName.containerOverrides.map( d => ({...d, ...opts}) )`

Comment: So the full code for my original comment would be `Object.assign(containerName.containerOverrides[0], opts); let overrides = containerName;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple non-mutation-y way to do it (I think):

```js
let opts = {
  'environment': [{
    'name': 'file',
  }]
};

let containerName = {
  'containerOverrides': [{
    'name': 'ecsTask'
  }]
};

let overrides = {
  containerOverrides: containerName.containerOverrides.map(
    (v) => Object.assign({}, v, opts)
  )
};

console.log(overrides);
```

It assumes that there aren't other properties on containerName that you want to preserve on overrides though.

Comment: Yup you nailed it, jeez, ty was stuck on this forever!

Comment: Combining map and assign makes so much sense since I am mixing objects and arrays!